# Rails: Advanced sql query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, matching

I am trying to show related jobs on show page of a given job. When user views any particular job, all related jobs should be displayed (must be displayed based on their weight) according to tag( I'm using acts-as-taggable-on gem), job function(job has_many:job_functions), experience & country(I'm using country-select gem).

If there is a job where all this criteria are similar to a given job it will have a weight = 100

else if another job where only tags and job function and country are similar it will have a weight =70 for example. So i can sort job based on weight

Actually I'm just finding related job based on tags

```
@related_jobs = Job.tagged_with(@job.tag_list, any: true)
```

And I can also find related job based on job function

```
@related_jobs = Job.includes(:functions)
                    .where('jobs.id != ?', @job.id)
                    .where(functions: { id: @job.functions.pluck(:id) } )
```

Comment: That's a great goal. What's your question?

Comment: how can i achieve this? where to put my code? it seem it will not be in the controller

Comment: No, this does not belong in the controller. This seems as though it should be a method on the Job class

Comment: But how can i compare a given job to others jobs in my job model, any help on how can i do it?

Comment: A model is a instance of job, you cannot have two calls compareable in model. Every time you call Job, you make a new instance of that Job model. Make two functions into the Job model,  and then compare them in controller or if it seems bad for you, make a concern for it under controllers.

Comment: you suggest that i create two method and after that i compare the two? but this don't appear to solve my question, because me i just want to sort related jobs based on weight so even if in my db there is only two jobs that  are similar 10% , it will be counted as similar but what you suggest will work only if there is a similarity of 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding related jobs according to some number of criteria, and weighting the related jobs according to the "closeness of match" certainly sounds like it is a task for the Job class. I'd create a method (perhaps 'get_related_weighted_jobs') in the Job class.

Inside that method, use the Job instance's attributes to find and assign weight to other matching jobs, then return the sorted list. The controller would just load the Job to show, then ask that job to find its matches.

```
def show
  @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  @related_jobs = @job.get_related_weighted_jobs()
end
```

Comment: So you suggestion is to create a method in the job model?

Comment: Yes. By making a method in the Job class, the method has access to the current job's attributes, and after all, in the MVC world, what entity is better qualified to find related jobs than an instance of the Job class itself. Not a task for a controller, certainly not a task for a view. (opinion -- Business logic, such as matching and weighting, belongs in models). A particular Job might match or weight differently depending on it's tags, function, experience, and country attributes.

Comment: But how I can for example compare just the current job with another job based only on tags in my model  can i call the @job = Job.find_by_slug(params[:id]) and after that work the same way as if i work in controller

Comment: Again, a method of the Job class. Find the @job by whatever finder method you want, then ask that job to do the work. The controller shouldn't necessarily know how to compare two jobs, but it can certainly know how to ask one instance of the Job class to compare itself to another instance of the Job class.

Comment: actually what I'm doing is   def final_score
    experience_score + ....
  end       def experience_score
    Job.where(experience == self.experience).count
  end     but this always return the number of job in my db instead of only the job that are similar in experience how can i resolve thsi

Comment: Perhaps
def experience_score
  res = 0
  unless self.experience.nil?
    res = Job.where('experience = ?', self.experience).count()
  end
  res
end